# How to execute a post request in Django from a Transactional email hyperlink click

Tags: python, django, email, post

My application sends an email to a user a when a specific event occurs.

I would like the user to be able to click on one of two buttons 'accept'/'decline' within the email body, and execute a request which my Django application can receive and process.

The request is sensitive, so the user needs to be authenticated (its ok if link also does an auto-login).

My intuition tells me that it will have to be done via a get() request, with a ton of logic that stores keys, verifies them, log's in the user, calls the respective 'accept/decline' function etc. It seems very convoluted for a process that now-days is quite common on emails. Is there a better solution / package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your accept / decline link is something like `/event/<event-id>/accept` and `/event/<event-id>/decline` I see no issues with just using that as a link. If the user clicks the link and is *not* logged in, they have to log in before the answer is accepted. Do a reroute on login.

The other option is to generate some keys for the event+user combo in a 2FA-like fashion.
Your event generates a random key like a UUID, you save that somewhere. The link is then something like `/event/accept/<UUID>` on the backend you translate that UUID to a combination of event and user.

It can be something simple like a event, user, key model.

```
class EventResponseKey(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    event = ForeignKey(Event)
    key = UUID()  # There some stuff here depending on your backend. Check the django docs.
```

Then you view is something like

```
class EventResponse(View):
    key = EventResponseKey.objects.filter(key=kwargs['key'])
    # your business logic here.
    # with key.user, key.event and key.key accessible.
    if kwargs['acceptdeny'] == 1:
       # user accepted event
    elseif kwargs['acceptdeny'] == 0:
       # user denied event
    return HttpResponse('your response has been recorded')
```

And urls like

```
# url
path('eventresponse/<UUID>/<acceptdeny>', EventResponse.as_view())
```

This is all pseudo code so don't copy paste it. But it should maybe jumpstart you on one way to solve this?

NB! Don't mess around with sending tokens! That's like putting the key to your door under you door mat. Either use keys so the only thing I could steal from that link in the email is to answer yes or no for somebody else. If you put csrf tokens in that email and I got a hold of it, I could get access to everything the user has access to. Force a login with redirect or let them click a link unauthenticated to accept or deny the event with a key. That key is then only used to accept or deny an event for a user. Then you have to ask yourself if that is safe enough for you use-case. Safest thing is to force them to log in, and then redirect them on login to the link they clicked.

Comment: thanks for the super detailed answer. That kind of what I was thinking, its great to have those insights too.